# extracting data from a string in PHP

Tags: php

I am a complete beginner in PHP.
I have several hundred product descriptions, for example here:

- Superpremium cat food light chicken 1 kg
- Superpremium cat food light chicken 10kg
- Superpremium cat food beef 2x10 kg
- Superpremium cat food beef 2 x 3,8 kg
- Superpremium cat food beef 2 x 2kg
- Superpremium cat food beef 42 x 85g

I would need to extract from the product name the name of flavor, quantity and weight like this:

**For example:**

From this: **Superpremium cat food beef 42 x 85g**

To this:

- Flavor: beef
- Number of pieces: 42
- Weight: 85
- KG/g: g

I tried to use an array, but it doesn't work for me at all.

There's a mess in the numbers. Sometimes 10kg is given, sometimes 10 kg with a gap as you can see in the examples above.

I have a list of name of the products (brands), list of flavors etc. so my idea was to use array and use if the string contains flavor then return "Flavor: beef" etc. I spent hours on looking how to use the functions but as a beginner have no idea how to make it work.

Thanks for help!

```
<?php
function flavor($product) {

$arr = array('turkey', 'chicken', 'fish', 'salmon', 'rabbit', 'beef', 'cod');
foreach ($arr as $product) {
    return $product;
    
}   
}

?>
```

Comment: How this string should look like after parsing "Superpremium cat food beef 2 x 3,8 kg" ?

Comment: Something like this: 
    Flavor: beef
    Number of pieces: 42
    Weight: 85
    KG/g: g

Comment: Is there any way you can get ahold of a more structured version of the data? Like, where each part is separated by a semicolon or comma or something like that?

Comment: I mean exactly this one "Superpremium cat food beef 2 x 3,8 kg"

Comment: @Tom, this is just a string... no comma... nothing like this.

Comment: Do you know that the name of the product itself is `Superpremium cat food` at this point? If not, how would you know which parts of `Superpremium cat food light chicken` are the product name, and which ones are the flavor ...?

Comment: @Slava It should look like this  Flavor: beef Number of pieces: 2 Weight: 3,8 KG/g: kg

Comment: @CBroe I have a list of name of the products (brands), list of flavors etc. so my idea was to use array and use if the string contains flavor then return "Flavor: beef" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to parse it, you could use regular expressions.

If you have T-Regx you can do

```php
$pattern = pattern('^(.*?) (?:(\d+) ?x ?)?((?:\d+)(?:,\d+)?) ?(k?g)$', 'm');
$match = $pattern->match('Superpremium cat food beef 2 x 3,8 kg');

$match->first(function (Detail $detail) {
    $text = $detail->get(1);
    $quantity = $detail->group(2)->orReturn(null);
    $amount = $detail->get(3);
    $unit = $detail->get(4);

    var_dump($text, $quantity, $amount, $unit);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not at my computer right now. I'll try later. Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

This how the solution can look like:

```
<?php

$description = <<<EOD
    Superpremium cat food light chicken 1 kg

    Superpremium cat food light chicken 10kg

    Superpremium cat food beef 2x10 kg

    Superpremium cat food beef 2 x 3,8 kg

    Superpremium cat food beef 2 x 2kg

    Superpremium cat food beef 42 x 85g
EOD;

preg_match_all("/.*food\s?([^\d]*)\s?([\d]+)\s*x?\s*([\d,]*)\s*([\w]*)/im", $description, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo 'Flavor: ' . $match[1] . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Number of pieces: ' . $match[2] . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Weight: ' . ($match[3] ?: 1) . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'kg/g: ' . $match[4] . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Explanations:

- `<<<EOD` means [heredoc syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for strings in PHP, it allows to handle multiline text in a single variable
- `preg_match_all` looks for pattern in the entire description text and save each piece in parentheses into $matches variable
- `im` in the end of regex pattern means `i` - case-insensitive, `m` - multiline
- `PREG_SET_ORDER` [constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) sets a needed order of found pieces in the `$matches` variable
- `PHP_EOL` constant stands for end-of-line symbol "\n", allows to print text on a new line
- `($match[3] ?: 1)` is a shortening for `($match[3] ? $match[3] : 1)` which means that if we have a value in `$match[3]` array index then we use this value, if no then we use 1 (one piece if no value for it in the text)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not at my computer right now. I'll try later. Thanks a lot again